Авто продление шаблонов на python
Хочу реализовать на python программу которая будет заполнять шаблон (с графическим интерфейсом). Часть кода уже написал, но не знаю как возможно сделать продление шаблона. Например: заполнил одно заявление, нажал на кнопку добавить ещё одного человека и в программе появилась новая строка для заполнения, а в итоговом файле было два заявления подряд. (то есть что бы всё было в одном итоговом файле, но использовался один шаблон).
Пример: Вот так выглядит изначальный шаблон

А вот так должен выглядеть итоговый файл (здесь он не заполнен, так как это пример)
То есть сделать так что бы можно было регулировать количество заполненных шаблонов в итоговом файле
Метки в самом шаблоне.doxc создал ({{пример}}, вот это проставил где надо)


А вопрос то в чем, что именно не получается?
